# Redis en typescript

Tags: typescript, redis

tengo un problema estoy intentando usar como key un token, y me tira error de type, probe usando el email y anda perfecto, pero yo quiero usar el token

```
const userCache = {
  email: user.email,
  password: user.password,
}

await clientRedis.setEx(token , 3600, JSON.stringify(userCache))
console.log(
  `Información del usuario almacenada en caché con clave: user:${token}`
)

const cacheMiddleware = async (
  req: AuthenticationRequest,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  await clientRedis.connect();
  const { token } = req.body;

  try {
    const cachedUserString = await clientRedis.get(token);
```

Comment: `console.log(typeof token)`? fijate el source de la libreria pero mepa q tiene q ser un string ( aunque redis soporte binary data as keys )